# leading 0 in month parameter making wrong output

Tags: php, date, mktime

Why the leading zero in the month parameter making wrong output?

```
echo date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, 09, 23, 2013));//output 2012-12-23
echo date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, 9, 23, 2013));//output 2013-09-23
```

Comment: Because `09` is not a valid value.

Comment: How 09 can not be a valid value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55327:

> Numbers with leading 0's are octal. 08 is an invalid value. See 
>   http://php.net/integer

If you prefix a number with a leading `0`, it marks the number as [Octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal_number). The octal numeral system uses the digits 0 to 7. So, `08` and `09` doesn't exist and are  invalid.

The second statement is correct, and that's the correct method:

```
echo date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, 9, 23, 2013));
```

Answer (score 1):

We can make this parameter as a string and it will work.

Try this:

```
echo date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, '09', 23, 2013));//output 2012-12-23
```